# Should I compare and set or just set?

Tags: java

I am writing a loop in java.

I have 2 integers dest & src. Please see question inline.

```
void test() {
    int[] arr = ..
    for (...) { //iterate over the array here.
        int src = arr[i];
        int dest= arr[j];

        if (dest != src) dest = src; //SHOULD I WRITE THIS?
            OR
        dest = src;                  //OR THIS?
        ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I compare and set or just set? depends on what you want to do it does not say what you want to do

Comment: the condition `dest != src` will always be true, because these are 2 different objects, so its redundent

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies--how's that?

Comment: Why do you initialize dest to `arr[j]` in the first place if you reassign it to src right after? What do you find the most obvious and readable?

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies Not necessarily; `dest` and `src` are primitive type variables, and either `i` and `j` could have the same value, thus pointing to the same element in the array, or the element at index `i` could have the same value as the element at index `j`.

Comment: What is the point of the compare in the first place? These are primitive integers, if the final effect is to have the value of `dest` equal to the value of `src`, directly assign `dest` to `src` and be done with it. For whatever reason you believe comparing two integers prior to setting (**except multithreading**, very far fetched especially with your example) don't do it. It'll likely just cause confusion in the future as to what you intended to do.

Answer (score 3):

if (dest != src) dest = src; 
        Has an extra comparison if they are already equal

dest = src 
        Has an extra set if they are already equal

I'm pretty sure both these "extras" have the same complexity O(1)
So it really should not matter, I think the second option (set without compare) looks cleaner, but I think at that point it is just a matter of opinion.

Comment: There is no N, so how could they be anything other than O(1)?

Answer (score 2):

If the semantics of your code are correct, you should write `dest = src`. Why? The `if` clause sets the value only, if the values are not equal. But this means, that if the clause is false, you can perform `dest = src` without changing anything (you will just reassign the value). The `if` just creates more instructions and both operands have to be fetched anyway.

EDIT: Did a quick test with this code. Once with the displayed version, once with `j = i` commented out and the `if` clause commented in.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int j = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        // if (j != i) {
        //     j = i;
        // }
        j = i;
    }
}
```

This is the stack code.

With `if`:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String...);
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: iconst_0
     2: aaload
     3: invokestatic  #16                 // Method java/lang/Integer.parseInt:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
     6: istore_1
     7: aload_0
     8: iconst_1
     9: aaload
    10: invokestatic  #16                 // Method java/lang/Integer.parseInt:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
    13: istore_2
    14: iload_2          // <-- Fetching 1st operand
    15: iload_1          // <-- Fetching 2nd operand
    16: if_icmpeq     21 // <-- THIS is the if
    19: iload_1
    20: istore_2
    21: return
```

without `if`

```
public static void main(java.lang.String...);
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: iconst_0
     2: aaload
     3: invokestatic  #16                 // Method java/lang/Integer.parseInt:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
     6: istore_1
     7: aload_0
     8: iconst_1
     9: aaload
    10: invokestatic  #16                 // Method java/lang/Integer.parseInt:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
    13: istore_2
    14: iload_1      // <-- Loading i
    15: istore_2     // <-- setting i's value to j
    16: return
```

As you see, the version without `if` needs 13 instructions. The `if` needs 14 or 16 instructions.

Comment: @hellyale those are not clock cycles. This is bytecode. Especially `iload` operations may take more than one clock cycle, since the program may have to fetch the operand from RAM. And yes, you should consider this things. You want to use caching effects as good as possible. EDIT: take a look at [this link](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832), you may be surprised.

Comment: @Turing85 Whilst bytecode analysis and performance optimization for these things are not unfounded. I do believe that code readability is much more important than micro optimizations. Had the bytecode shown less instructions in the a "compare then set" example, I still believe in this case would probably just confuse the programmer in the future about the intention of the code. Besides, if the code is so time critical to the point where individual if statements are a performance bottleneck, why not just port the whole segment into native code using assembly?